# Entity framework core model with custom property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use the entity framework core (db first) and need to extend model with custom property.

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }        
    public int SchoolId { get; set; } 
    public School School { get; set; }            
}

public partial class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to use partial class for display name of student's school, but I do not have access to DbContext here.

```
public partial class Student
{
    public string SchoolName { get{return //Name of school from db} }
}
```

What is the best approach?

Comment: Why do you need this at all? You can just do `someStudent.School.Name`

Comment: And make sure you `Include(s => s.School)` to populate the School navigation property when requesting Student from the database.

Comment: @DavidG how would you solve if the property involved some actual proccessing, pulling other 3 related entities? Have fun debugging which of the properties the user code forgot to pull...

Comment: @wondra That's what testing is for. Even with this extra property, the query will have to populate it manually.